# How to disable click events for entire children except one selected child in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Scenario: I have number of children in Listview.builder. For every children there is button which invokes TTS(text to speech). I wanted when any one of child is pressed rest  all children should be in Listview.builder un-clickable till pressed child finishes its TTS.

I got answer from google like absorb pointer, ignore pointer to solve this.
But i dont know how to implement above scenario using these widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Store a `bool` in the `State` of the class enclosing the `ListView.builder`. This `bool` should store if one of the children is currently doing its TTS. If it is `true` you should set all of the `onPressed`(or equivalent) method to `null` to prevent other taps from triggering an action. Ex:

```dart
bool hasBeenClicked = false;

void yourTTSMethod() {
  setState(() {
    hasBeenClicked = true;
  });

  ... //Do normal method body

  setState(() {
    hasBeenClicked = true;
  });
}

//In build method with each `List` item:
GestureDetector(//Just for sample, use whatever click detector you're currently using
  onTap: hasBeenClicked ? null : yourTTSMethod
)
```